# deactivating all standard mousevents XTK

Tags: javascript, events, mouse, webgl, xtk

I've got a volume and a mousemove event within a mousedown event.
what I want to achieve is to move the mouse while the button is still pressed, change the slice via IndexX++/--

AND

stop the volume from being rotated.

I need to "pause" all standard mouse events (or at least the rotateevent) and reactivate them
when the mouseup event is fired.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: I also had some changes to do in the XTK interactor, my approche was to create my own instance of the XTK Framework with modifying the sources and compiling them after. You could do that : add an attribute "this._isBlocked = false" in X.interactor3D, then test it when mouse move (in onMouseMovementInside_), change it when the button is pressed/unpressed (onKey_ I think).

Answer (score 1):

You could either modify XTK to provide the flag as Ricola3D mentioned or you could disable all interactions with the `renderer.interactor.config` options:

```
*  config.MOUSEWHEEL_ENABLED: true
*  config.MOUSECLICKS_ENABLED: true
*  config.KEYBOARD_ENABLED: true
```

Then, you could write your own interaction handler by observing events directly on the canvas - completely outside of XTK and just call XTK functionality to modify the view.